# react-native doctor: Accept IntelliJ IDEA instead of Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, intellij-idea

I created my firsted react-native project using `npx react-native init`. Then I opened it using **IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate**. I think it can do everything that **Android Studio** can. But `react-native doctor` says:

```bash
> react-native doctor
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies

Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 33.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
```

How do I tell to react-native **IntelliJ IDEA** is same as **Android Studio**?

I also, don't know why it doesn't recognize Android SDK, even though `Android_HOME` is correctly set to Android SDK folder.

Comment: Independent of your question if you use Android Studio or IntelliJ: Android SDK is required and to my knowledge Android SDK is no longer available as download you have to install Android Studio and on first start it will download and install Android SDK.

Comment: @Robert "Android SDK" manager is available under "Settings > Languages & Frameworks" in IntelliJ IDEA. Note that I can even run the application on the emulator. But there are some errors and warnings in IDE, `react-native doctor` and ...

Comment: @Robert I already have set it and related paths according to https://developer.android.com/tools/variables. Commands like `echo %ANDROID_HOME%`, `where emulator`, `where adb` and ... have the expected output.

Comment: Was Android detected as a framework in your project in IDEA (did you see a popup about it)? You may need to go to 'Project Structure > Facets' and add an Android facet there manually. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/android-facet-page.html